# Alpha equivalence in Haskell (Lambda terms)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a function in Haskell which checks whether two Lambda terms are alpha equivalent.

```
alphaEq :: LExp -> LExp -> Bool
alphaEq (ID x) (ID y) = x == y
alphaEq (LAMBDA x1 e1) (LAMBDA x2 e2) = alphaEq e1 (substitute x2 (ID x1) e2)
alphaEq (APP e1 f1) (APP e2 f2) = alphaEq e1 e2 && alphaEq f1 f2
alphaEq _ _ = False

substitute :: Var -> LExp -> LExp -> LExp
substitute v k (ID x) = if v == x then k else (ID x)
substitute v k (LAMBDA x e) = if v == x then (LAMBDA x e) else (LAMBDA x (substitute v k e))
substitute v k (APP e1 e2) = APP (substitute v k e1) (substitute v k e2)
```

This however doesn't do exactly what I need, as, for example, this input:

```
alphaEq (LAMBDA "w" (LAMBDA "z" (APP (ID "z") (ID "w")))) (LAMBDA "x" (LAMBDA "y" (APP (ID "y") (ID "x"))))
```

which of course is alpha equivalent evaluates as False. Can you see what am I doing wrong and correct me?

Comment: Your definition for two `ID` values is wrong. Alpha equivalence is precisely the notion that names *don't* matter, and you are explicitly checking if two names are the same.

Comment: @chepner Names under the binders don't matter. When you're already comparing the free variables, the names certainly do matter. How else would you differentiate `\x -> \y -> x` from `\x -> \y -> y`?

Comment: That being said, I cannot actually reproduce the problem: _on my machine_, it outputs `True`?

Comment: Here is a better example where your code breaks: `t3 = (LAMBDA "x" (LAMBDA "y" (ID "y")))` vs `t4 = (LAMBDA "z" (LAMBDA "x" (ID "z")))`. It's clearly not alpha-equivalent, but your code gives "true"

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That's just it: given two `ID` values, you don't *know* if  you are comparing two free variables or two bound variables or even a free and a bound variable. (Or are the other definitions ensuring that the `ID` case is only reached when the appropriate context has already been determined?)

Comment: The part `... else (LAMBDA x (substitute v k e))` is wrong. There you want to perform capture-avoiding substitution instead, renaming `x` to be a fresh variable in `k` and `e` before applying the substitution. In pseudo code, `(\x.y){x/y}` must be `(\z.x)` where `z` is fresh. (I recommend reading [this answer of mine for more discussion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97700/43599)).

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, defining and testing alpha equivalence using substitution like you've attempted is harder than it first seems. Probably you could fix your code by focusing on the particular problems that are already visible, but I'd suggest a whole other approach:

**Translate both expressions into a new canonical form that can be compared literally.**

You have some options for what that new form should be. My instinct would be to a new AST data-type expressing your lambda caculus in [De Bruijn indecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index).